# NODEjs: TypeError: The "password" argument must be of type string or an instance of ArrayBuffer, Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, node-modules

I keep getting this error in my terminal when I run my app but I do not have a password variable anywhere in my code

```
TypeError: The "password" argument must be of type string or an instance of ArrayBuffer, Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined
    at check (node:internal/crypto/scrypt:89:14)
    at Object.scryptSync (node:internal/crypto/scrypt:70:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/gokeadewuyi/abc/algorand/node_modules/@african-blockchain-center/common/build/utils/encryption.js:8:30)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._compile (/Users/gokeadewuyi/abc/algorand/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:568:25)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at require.extensions..jsx.require.extensions..js (/private/var/folders/7m/t45z59v16x51rby86nhtvx2m0000gn/T/ts-node-dev-hook-9974711466048651.js:114:20)
    at Object.nodeDevHook [as .js] (/Users/gokeadewuyi/abc/algorand/node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/hook.js:63:13)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
```

this is my app.ts file

```
import express from "express";
import "express-async-errors";
import { json } from "body-parser";
import cookieSession from "cookie-session";
import {
  errorHandler,
  NotFoundError,
  currentUser,
} from "@african-blockchain-center/common";

const app = express();
app.set("trust proxy", true);
app.use(json());
app.use(
  cookieSession({
    signed: false,
    secure: true,
  })
);
app.use(currentUser);

app.all("*", async (req, res) => {
  throw new NotFoundError();
});

app.use(errorHandler);

export { app };
```

and my index.ts file

```
import { app } from "./app";

const start = async () => {
  if (!process.env.JWT_KEY) {
    throw new Error("JWT_KEY must be defined");
  }
 

  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("algorand-service reporting for duty!");
  });
};

start();
```

I have been debugging for several hour but can't solve the issue, I have checked the imported node modules for the "password" variable but could not find it as well

Answer (score 1):

Is the `@african-blockchain-center/common` module maintained by you or your organization? That seems to be the source of the trouble.

Deep within the belly of that package, it expects `ENCRYPTION_SECRET` and `ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM` environment variables to function.

**To demonstrate:**
Try setting the environment variable in your bashrc or zshrc file (or via the terminal or in your .env file — however you prefer to skin your env cat!)

(PS: If you do it via your bashrc/zshrc file, don't forget to run `source` against the file afterwards)

[image: Snapshot of my .zshrc file]

Restart your nodeJS browser, and you should be good to go.

[image: Server running now]